# Youtube images are broken in firefox

Tags: image, firefox, youtube

Youtube images are broken in firefox. When I use the web developer extention to reload the images they appear briefly for a few seconds and then go blank again. The videos work fine but many of the buttons show their alt attribues instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried clearing cache/temporary files of your browser?

Comment: I have this problem too. The icons wont load, however the youtube icon in the top left corner has changed and now loads properly even though all the images are loaded from the same site. What is different?